# How to add udhcpd in yocto?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, busybox, access-point, hostapd

I want to set my wireless interface (mlan0) to access point mode. I have `hostapd` in `/usr/sbin`. But I don't have `udhcpd`.

I have `udhcpc` in `/sbin` though. I checked my `busybox.bb` file and found `CONFIG_UDHCPD=y` in `defconfig`. Not sure what i am missing here.

Comment: What poky branch you are using ?

Comment: @TalelBELHADJSALEM: It's poky sumo - 2.5.3

Answer (score 0):

`dhcp` recipe provides different packages:

`poy/meta/recipes-connectivity/dhcp/dhcp.inc`:

```
PACKAGES += "dhcp-libs dhcp-server dhcp-server-config dhcp-client dhcp-relay dhcp-omshell"
```

You just need to add:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " dhcp-server"
```

**EDIT**

Busybox provides udhcpd in separate package, so you need to add:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " busybox-udhcpd"
```

this package only installs `busybox-udhcpd` binary under `/etc/init.d/` if `CONFIG_UDHCPD=y`

Comment: This will give me ```dhcpd```. But not ```udhcpd```.

Comment: Check my **EDIT**